# How to print out Python message to linux stdout immediately

Tags: python, linux, shell

Usually I'd like to run my python code in linux as the following:

```
nohup python test.py > nohup.txt 2>&1 &
```

in the file test.py, I often use **`print`** to print out some messages to stdout. But actually I have to wait very long time then could see the messages were printed out to nohup.txt. How can I make it print out quickly.

Comment: Would you be able to insert calls to `flush` in your test program?

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could call `flush` on `stdout`.  If it is possible and practical for you to adjust your code to flush your buffers after the `print` call, in `test.py`:

```
from sys import stdout
from time import sleep

def log():
    while True:
        print('Test log message')
        # flush your buffer
        stdout.flush()
        sleep(1)
```

While running this logging test, you can check the `nohup.txt` file and see the messages being printed out in realtime.

Answer (score 3):

just make sure you have `coreutils` installed

```
stdbuf -oL nohup python test.py > nohup.txt 2>&1 &
```

this just sets buffering to off for this command ... you should see immediate output

(you might need nohup before stdbuf ... im not sure exactly)

alternatively ... just put at the top of `test.py`

```
import sys
sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', 0)
```